# Facebook authentication with Firebase in React Application gives Firebase error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, facebook, facebook-login

I am trying to integrate google and facebook login with firebase in my react application. I followed all the steps. Google authentication works fine but facebook authenticaton gives error. The post `POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com` is failed with code 400.

[image]

I have tried many solutions but nothing works.

My code App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { authentication } from './firebase-config';
import { signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider, FacebookAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

function App() {
  const signInWithGoogle = () => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    signInWithPopup(authentication, provider).then((re) => {
      console.log(re)
    })
     .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
     })
  }
 const signInWithFacebbok = () => {
   const fbprovider = new FacebookAuthProvider();
   signInWithPopup(authentication, fbprovider).then((re) => {
     console.log(re)
    })
     .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Log in WIth Google</button>
      <br></br>
      <button onClick={signInWithFacebbok}>Log in WIth Facebook</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

firebase-config.js

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "key",
    authDomain: "domain",
    projectId: "id",
    storageBucket: "bucket",
    messagingSenderId: "senderId",
    appId: "appId"
 };
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const authentication = getAuth(app);
```

Comment: "Error validating client secret" sounds like you did probably not configure your app credentials correctly.

Comment: Yes, this was the issue. Thank you so much